# How to use slicer in power bi as a keyword search in dataset which contains the keywords?

Tags: powerbi, contains, keyword

Objective:
To create 2 visuals in power bi to allow user when they click the keyword in slicer, the corresponding table will only shows the line item that contains the keyword selected

DATASET:

| Activity | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Company dinner at hotel ABCD | $100 |
| Lunch at the hills | $70 |
| Flower wraith 20/09/23 | $20 |
| Tokens for retirement | $20 |
| Dinner with MR ABCD | $60 |
| Staff XXX claims for dinner 24/06/23 | $50 |

### -

- 
- 
- 

*Thousands of line items

POWER BI:

VISUAL 1:

SLICER

| Keywords |
| --- |
| Dinner |
| Lunch |
| Family |
| Gifts |
| Tokens |
| Flower |

VISUAL 2:

| Activity | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Company dinner at hotel ABCD | $100 |
| Lunch at the hills | $70 |
| Flower wraith 20/09/23 | $20 |
| Tokens for retirement | $20 |
| Dinner with MR ABCD | $60 |
| Staff XXX claims for dinner 24/06/23 | $50 |

*The user click/select one of the keyword for example in this case "Dinner" the table only show the line item

| Activity | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Company dinner at hotel ABCD | $100 |
| Dinner with MR ABCD | $60 |
| Staff XXX claims for dinner 24/06/23 | $50 |
| Total | $210 |

I have tried using DAX contains strings, adjusting the filter well but all seems returning error or nil result

Comment: Update the question with the expressions you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Measure similar to:

```
Keyword count = 
  IF(
    ISFILTERED(Keywords[Keywords]),
    SUMX(
      DISTINCT('Keywords'[Keywords]),
      COUNTROWS(FILTER('Activity', CONTAINSSTRING('Activity'[Activity], [Keywords])))
    ),
    COUNTROWS(Activity)
  )
```

Add this new measure to your visual as a Visual Filter, and set it to `is not blank`, in the Filter pane.

Suggest your keyword list is non-plural (gift instead of gifts as an example).

Comment: hi thank you, I have created the measure and add into the visual but still there is nothing showing up when I selected a keyword from the slicer

Comment: Do you have any relationship between the two tables? Can you share a link to a sample PBIX?

Comment: I deactivated the relationship and its working now. thank you so much!